# Custom Tumblr photosets with infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I've been wondering how I could get this code for custom tumblr photoset sizes to work with infinite scrolling

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* Photoset Resize Code by Kevin - EXCOLO.TUMBLR.COM */
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function photosetResize() {
        $('iframe.photoset').each(function(){
            var newSize = 200;
            var newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('500',newSize);
            $(this).attr('src', newSrc).width(newSize);        
            var high = $(this).css('height');
            var calculate = parseInt(high, 10)* newSize/500;
            $(this).css('height', calculate);
        });
    }
    photosetResize();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean? i did not comment on your question, just added missing tags I thought would be useful for people to be able to find your question and correctly relate it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would need to modify it to accept a jQuery object / collection:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $iframes = $('iframe.photoset');

function photosetResize($iframes) {
    $iframes.each(function(){
        var newSize = 200;
        var newSrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('500',newSize);
        $(this).attr('src', newSrc).width(newSize);        
        var high = $(this).css('height');
        var calculate = parseInt(high, 10)* newSize/500;
        $(this).css('height', calculate);
    });
}

photosetResize( $iframes );

});
```

You will need to find the new *photosets* when infinite scroll has completed via its callback.

```
var $newIframes = $(arrayOfNewElems).find($iframes.selector);
```

Hope that helps!